# Can you write tests for Express Google Cloud Functions?

Tags: express, google-cloud-functions, tdd

I have built a Cloud Function express API and I would like to know how to write tests for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question : of course, you *can* write tests for Google Cloud Functions. I will even add that, like any other application, you **should** write tests.

You can take a look at the [Cloud Functions documentation about Testing and CI/CD](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/testing). In the Node.js part, it shows how to test *Cloud Functions* with [Mocha](https://mochajs.org/) as a test framework and [Sinon](https://sinonjs.org/) as a mocking framework. The testing process should be part of your local development and your CI tool, if you have one.

Basically, there are 3 types of tests :

- unit tests
- integration tests
- system tests

In **unit tests**, you should mock your HTTP framework (Express) to test small parts of your code.

In **integration tests**, you should mock any external dependency between your *Function* and other components (for example, if your *Function* writes data to a *Cloud SQL* database, then you should mock this *Cloud SQL* database).

In **system tests**, you should deploy your *Function* to a specific GCP environment (most probably an isolated project), to ensure that your Function interacts well with other GCP components, or starts when you trigger it.

Finally, there was previously a [Cloud Functions Node.js emulator](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/emulator) to locally test *Functions*. This have been deprecated, but replaced by the [Functions Framework](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/functions-framework), that also can be used to "*spin up a local development server for quick testing*".

Comment: How to mock in integration tests